# How to make the program stop reading the codes?

Tags: c, arrays

What I want to do is: The user inputs a string; for example: `12345,44,55,66`. I've created a function to check if the first 5 characters aren't digits, then the program will output an error message and if the 6th character is not `,`, the program will also output an error message. My problem is that I want the program to stop reading the codes if an error is detected (won't print if there is an error). So how I can stop the program from continuing reading the codes? Here is what I have written so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void checkstudentID(char temp[]);

main()
{
    char temp[10000];
    char m0[10000];
    gets(temp);
    checkstudentID(temp);   
    printf("%s",temp);          
    return 0;
}

void checkstudentID(char temp[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(temp[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Student ID must contain only integers.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (temp[6] != *(","))
    {
              printf("Student ID must contain only 6 integers.\n");
              return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not return any value from a `void` function, use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`, and  `int main(void)`

Comment: Didn't mean to hijack the thread but can someone explain how `*(",")` is interpreted by the c compiler? This is the first time I'm seeing that kind of syntax and the compiler didn't complain at all!?!?

Comment: @yasouser Make a new thread with this question so we can answer it properly.

Comment: @RedX: Figured it out. Its fetching the first character from the string literal. I have never seen that syntax before to compare against a character!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good habit that **Don't make multiple exit points**. So accordingly it's not a good taste to use `exit()` in subfunction. I would suggest to make the subfunctions return values to tell their status to the main function.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int checkstudentID(char temp[]);
void main()
{
    char temp[10000];
    char m0[10000];
    gets(temp);
    switch(checkstudentID(temp))
    {
        case 0: printf("%s",temp);break;
        case 1: printf("Student ID must contain only integers.\n"); break;
        case 2: printf("Student ID must contain only 6 integers.\n"); break;
    }
}

int checkstudentID(char temp[])
{
    int i;
    int ID_status = 0;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        if (0==isdigit(temp[i]))
        {
            ID_status = 1;
            break;
        }
    if (temp[6]!=',') ID_status = 2;
    return ID_status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exit()` to stop reading codes. You can do like

```
void checkstudentID(char temp[])
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    if (isdigit(temp[i])==0)
    {
        printf("Student ID must contain only integers.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
if (temp[6]!=','))
{
          printf("Student ID must contain only 6 integers.\n");
          exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning C, could you explain why your last if statement compared using pointers rather than char equality? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Another way to read only 6 character is:

```
//gets(temp);
scanf("%6s", temp);
```

Even if the user enters more than 6 characters, `temp` will have only 6 characters stored.

Comment: Please leave comment as to why you are voting down the answer. The original question is: "So how I can stop the program from continuing reading the codes?". My solution is to accept only the first 6 chars of the input because the student id is 6 character long. The suggestion is to replace `gets(temp);`.